# No module named 'cuda._lib'; 'cuda' is not a package

Tags: python, pycharm, cuda

After following the steps on [cuda-python](https://nvidia.github.io/cuda-python/install.html) to install cuda-python with conda instruction, I try to

```
from cuda import cuda, nvrtc
```

as in the example in the pycharm python console, but it raises an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\hierot\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\PyCharm Community Edition 2022.1.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "cuda\cuda.pyx", line 1, in init cuda.cuda
    # Copyright 2021-2022 NVIDIA Corporation.  All rights reserved.
  File "D:\PyCharm Community Edition 2022.1.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cuda._lib'; 'cuda' is not a package
```

But the code above can be successfully run in the terminal

```
(hierot) D:\Projects\SimPlatform>python
Python 3.9.13 (main, Aug 25 2022, 23:51:50) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from cuda import cuda, nvrtc
>>>
```

Please help me with the problem, thanks in advance. Further information provided on request.

I searched with

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xxx'
```

Solutions suggest configure correct python interpreter, but I believe my interpreter is already properly configured.

And search with

```
No module named 'xxx'; 'yyy' is not a package
```

Some says the cause is the name cuda is shadowed by the package name cuda, but I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Oh I finally solved this problem, by configuring interpreter path, which in the beginning I added site-packages/cuda because I was trying to debug another problem at that time, and thus the shadow of the name cuda. (The image below is after deleting the redundant path)

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).